# SQOOP uneven output file size

Tags: oracle, hadoop, export, sqoop

I have a huge news database, but whenever i am trying to sqoop it, it writes to 2-3 files rather than whole 200.

```
sqoop import -D mapred.map.max.attempts=4 \
  -D dfs.blocksize=1073741824 \
  -D oraoop.block.allocation=RANDOM \
  -D mapred.job.queue.name=default \
  -m 200 \
  --split-by AUTHOR_ID \
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@$127.0.0.1:1521:SRDB \
  --username abc \
  --password 1234 \
  --table L.ARTICLE \
  --null-string '' \
  --null-non-string '' \
  --target-dir /data/output1.0
  --outdir /tmp/output
```

But, when I ran it, I was getting 202 files instead of 200. And among those only 3 files has data and rest of the output files are empty.

What am I doing wrong? Any hint would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting on `AUTHOR_ID`

Most probable reason -

`AUTHOR_ID`*(on which you are splitting)*  is not uniformly distributed.

Internally sqoop is fetching min and max values for splitting columns.

```
SELECT MIN(AUTHOR_ID) and MAX(AUTHOR_ID) FROM L.ARTICLE
```

Say output of the above query is:

```
1,20000
```

Now based on these values it will make range queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM L.ARTICLE WHERE AUTHOR_ID>=1 AND AUTHOR_ID<100
SELECT * FROM L.ARTICLE WHERE AUTHOR_ID>=100 AND AUTHOR_ID<200
SELECT * FROM L.ARTICLE WHERE AUTHOR_ID>=200 AND AUTHOR_ID<300
.
. 
.
SELECT * FROM L.ARTICLE WHERE AUTHOR_ID>=19900 AND AUTHOR_ID<20000
```

(You can observe this in sqoop command itself. Add `--verbose` in your sqoop commands so that you can see extended logs.)

**Now if data is not uniformly distributed then only few mappers will fetch record and others are empty.**

Let's say for example if in your data we have the following case:

```
author_id record 
1 record1
19900 record19900  
19901 record19901 
19902 record19902 
19903 record19903 
19904 record19904 
19905 record19905
19906 record19906
```

The mapper#0 will sqoop 1 record and mapper#199 will sqoop 7 records. You can extrapolate this case with a huge number of records.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very nice write up.

Comment: In that case, how am I make sure same AUTHOR_ID will not be in across multiple files?

Comment: @Gon I did not get it. Every file is created by some range query on AUTHOR_ID and every query is different so there will be different AUTHOR_ID in different files.

Comment: Sqoop already provided that behavior. Let's say mapper#0 will take care of  (AUTHOR_ID>=1 AND AUTHOR_ID<100). So it will produce 1 file with all the records between that range.

Comment: @devツ, for instance, there are 3 AUTHOR_IDs while AUTHOR_ID is not a key for the table. When I export it using sqoop, I want it to be in 200 files, also I want same AUTHOR_ID to be in the same file rather than 1 of the AUTHOR_ID in file 1 and the other 2 in file 2. I thought to do it by split-by, but as it causes an issue with uneven distribution, I am wondering if there's an alternate way.

Comment: @Gon Is there any specific reason to store each AUTHOR_ID in a separate file? Splitting is done to do the task in parallel i.e. for faster import from RDBMS to HDFS. You should split on primary key or another integer column (uniformly distributed) if the faster import is what you what to achieve here.